# Sending object using spring boot JMS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms

I made 2 classes : 1 to send and 1 to receive. Currently I can send just a basic string and it works well

Sender

```
@Component
public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    //Script must be serializable
    public void testSend(/*Script*/String message)
    {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("my-destination", message);      
    }
}
```

Receiver

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-destination")
    public void receive(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        context.close();
    }
}
```

I can't implement proper code here, if someone can just show me how to do, I'd grateful

I would make almost the same thing but to send complex java objects (serializable). And the reeceiver class should be able to recognize the class of the object.

Comment: What isn't working, currently it is quite unclear what you are asking. Please clarify what isn't working as expected. Also is this a single application, multiple or....?

Comment: It's writen in the title, I want to make almost the same thing but sending complex java objects, currently I can send only a String. Sorry I modified my post

Comment: Just send an object... As already stated it isn't clear what you want, what have you tried.

Comment: I have tried to make an instance of my class (just a basic class with few attributes and getter / setter) but when I try to send it using the same way that I did for String it does not work. I think that I have to use an other way for instance of my own class but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What didn't work... Just stating it doesn't work isn't clear enough... Also as I requested what have you tried that doesn't work. Also what doesn't work, do you get an exception on sending, don't you receive anything.. What... be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly creates a ByteMessage and serialize your object in (the object have to be Serializable) :

```
    this.jmsTemplate.send("my-destination", new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bOut);
            oOut.writeObject(_object); // where object is the object to serialize
            bytes[] data = bOut.toByteArray();
            return session.createByteMessage(data);
        }
    });
```

and

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "my-destination")
    public void receive(Message message) {
        final BytesMessage message = (BytesMessage) _message;
        final byte[] array = new byte[Long.valueOf(message.getBodyLength()).intValue()];
        message.readBytes(array);
        final ByteArrayInputStream bIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(_bytes);
        final ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(bIn);
        Object obj = oIn.readObject(); // the deserialized object
    }
```

Comment: If the object is serializable you can simply use an object message and that is what spring kms already does out of the box. No need to mess around with your own message creation.

Comment: That what I searched, do you have a simple example to help me ? Otherwise I can just search by myself when I know what I havee to use. Thank you

Comment: I used to have trouble with ObjectMessage, this solution worked better in my case, notably because we can use your own serializer if needed. But for simple objects MessageObject will probably do the trick.

Comment: If you need a different serializer you might be better of using a `MarshallingMessageConverter` instead of trying to do it yourself. Try to work with the framework not around it :)

Comment: Thank you ! I will try and I will post what it working in my case :)